# Array index changing

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

If i want  a variable  to be equal to another variable  in any moment I use a pointer :
p=&a
 *p is always equal to a, irrespective if a changes.
However if I want a variable to be equal with arr[Id] but the Id , index of the array , always changes in my program I can't use :

`p1=&Id
 p2=&arr[*p1]`

because *p2 will always be equal to the value of the array at the initial index, and if the index changes *p2 won't change with it .
How can I resolve this problem and get *p2 to change every time Id changes?

Comment: afaik, no way to do it

Comment: XY problem here, I guess. What are you really trying to achieve? Because of `p2=arr` and `p2[changing_id]` can be the solution here.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see why it works for the first instance

```
p = &a;
```

Here `a` has an address, say `0x100`, and this address is stored in the variable `p`. Now, even if `a` changes, the address remains the same, and the value of `p` will still be `0x100` .`*p` will give the updated value of a.

For the second case,

```
p = &a[d]
```

Here if `a` is `0x100` and `d` is 5 and `a` is a char array, then `p` will hold the value `0x105` If index `d` changes, then the address to be used in the array will change, e.g. if `d` is `2` then the address to use is `0x102`

As the address changes, the value of `p` will have to change and it has to be reassigned before the next use.